# 360dp in MDPI not matching in xxhdpi

Tags: android

i have a image that on mDPI is 360dp and that takes up the entire width of the screen.  But when i view the image on nexus 5x api 23 xxhdpi  scren it does not take up the entire width of the screen.  I thought 1dp equals 1px on MDPI so i could use that as a standard. so then 360dp on MDPI is max width therefore it will be max width on all densities ? what am i missing ?

This is what i have tried. Compare this screens size:

[image]

giving this full screen output:

[image]

this this one with the same 360dp:

[image]

giving a output with the image not taking up the full screen, why :

[image]

is this why constraintLayout is recommended , using ratios ?

Answer (score 0):

i finally figured this out. this is one reason constraintLayout was built to rectify these issues.  in this particuular case it was about aspect ratio in a view i was using.  so to make it take up the entire space of the activity left and right i did the following and the aspect ratio is maintained. keep i mind i wanted a 360 x 500 ratio:

```
 <com.mobile.myapp.customViews.SwippableViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/pager"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,360:500"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[this overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzmB3UxxhaA) was very useful for me to learn constraintLayout.

also the other way to guarantee this would be to use a viewgroup somewhat forgotten now as its deprecated:  [android percentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)